# How to filter firestore collection in Swift?

Tags: swift, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I was able to get the following code from google firestore documentation to use the filter in Swift

```
let query = db.collection("cities").whereFilter(Filter.orFilter([
    Filter.whereField("capital", isEqualTo: true),
    Filter.whereField("population", isGreaterThanOrEqualTo: 1000000);
]))
```

I added the firebase package into my swift project using package manager of Xcode and imported the module `FirebaseFirestore` to be able to access the functionalities.

The issue is I wasn't able to access `.whereFilter` as indicated in the documentation. All what I was able to access is .whereField

I was looking to achieve the following code

```
import Foundation
import FirebaseFirestore


receivedOffersListenerRegistration = db.collection(CollectionName.offers.name)
            .whereFilter(Filter.orFilter([
                Filter.whereField("senderUserId", isEqualTo: userId),
                Filter.whereField("recipientUserId", isEqualTo: userId)
            ]))
            .addSnapshotListener { [weak self] snapShot, error in
```

I am getting error message **Cannot find 'Filter' in scope** the moment I enforce to use Filter inside the query.

What are the ways to be able to access `.whereFilter`?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: The problem is I am not being able to access the `.whereFilter` as part of the query function of Firestore. In the documentation it is marked that we can use the `.whereFilter` but when I am trying the code, I am not getting the option `.whereFilter` as indicated in the documentation. My question is how to access the **Filter** as part of the query. Or is there any alternative to access the **Filter**?

Comment: My first part of the question is extracted from Firestore documentation and the second part of my question is what I am looking to achieve as code. Because this option `.whereFilter` not appearing when I click the **.**

Comment: I am getting error message **Cannot find 'Filter' in scope** the moment I enforce to use **Filter** inside the query as I mentioned in my second part of my question.

Comment: check this article from firebase documentation https://cloud.google.com/firestore/docs/query-data/queries#or_queries but in practice the **Filter** is not available

Comment: @abed for readability it is preferred to [edit] your question with additional info, instead of adding it in comments. See also [ask].

Comment: @koen okay will do

Comment: Show us the `Filter` object.

Comment: @trndjc this is the point. First i used pod to install firebase SDK and I was able to access `Filter` object as indicated above in my original question 2nd section. But when I moved to Xcode package, I lost my access to this object. I am not sure if I am missing anything related to importing a particular module.

Comment: You don't need to use this `Filter` class to construct a Firestore query. IMO, this object shouldn't even be in the Swift documentation because there is no context for it. In fact, I've never seen this class until now and I've used Firestore extensively. Is there a particular reason you want to use it? To use Firestore in its full capacity, you don't need it.

Comment: @trndjc thank you for your reply. As i noted before, I used `Filter` before when I installed Firestone sdk using the pod. For what I need it is as follow, I need to filter my fetch results according to 2 fields i.g. `sender` or `recipient` equal to a particular value. The `whereField` doesn't help because it makes `and` when nested while I want it to be `sender` or `recipient` to equal a value. Do you have any alternative to achieve this in building the `Query` in swift?

Comment: I suspect what happened is that this `Filter` class was exposed to the programmer in a previous SDK version and later hidden in an update, which would explain why it was within scope in one version and not the other. But to be clear, you want to make a query where `sender` equals `abc123` *OR* `recipient` equals `abc123`? Or do you want to achieve something else? Give me an example, like I just did, and we can figure it out.

Comment: @trndjc thank you for your assistance. yes indeed. I want to build a query to fetch users records from users collection where `senderId` _OR_ `recipientId` **field names** equal to a value `abc123`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two ways I would consider structuring this query.

```
[transactions] <-- collection
    <autoID> <-- document
        - sender: abc123
        - recipient: xyz456
```

The first way: you can simply perform two queries and combine them. You can search the collection for documents where `sender` is equal to `abc123` and then a second query where `recipient` is equal to `abc123` and combine the results on the client.

```
[transactions]
    <autoID>
        - sender: abc123
        - recipient: xyz456
        - partyMembers: [abc123, xyz456]
```

The second way: create a new field in the document, maybe called `partyMembers`, which would be an array of all the members in this transaction/party (senders, recipients, etc.), and then search the collection for documents where `partyMembers` array-contains `abc123`.

https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/queries#array_membership

In Swift, this would look something like:

```
transactions.whereField("partyMembers", arrayContains: "abc123")
```

Comment: thank you, I already implemented solution 1 and yes it is working fine (but i need to maintain a logic to combine the results before making them available to be used). i guess solution 2 is cleaner in terms of less code and there is no need to maintain extra code to combine results.